# Running C Program on Heroku: No such file

Tags: python, c, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to open a C program in a python script running on a Heroku dyno. The Python script works fine locally, but on the dyno it says that the executable cannot be found. The line to run the program in Python is:

`proc = subprocess.Popen(["./backend/test-print"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`,

where `backend` is the folder that contains the program `test-print` and the Python script. I run the Python scripy from the folder root so it finds the script just fine. The Heroku logs say:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './backend/test-print'`.

If I run bash on the dyno and try to run the program manually, it gives the same error:

```
Running bash on ⬢ ******** ... up, run.8123 (Eco)
~ $ cd backend
~/backend $ ls
server.py  test-print
~/backend $ ./test-print
bash: ./test-print: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. I built the program test-print on my local machine (not the one I am running the program on).

I tried putting the program in the root `/app` folder to see if it would be found then, but that did not work.

EDIT: I should also add that when I `cat test-print`, it finds the file fine and prints its contents.

EDIT: `type test-print` outputs

```
~/backend $ type test-print 
bash: type: test-print: not found
```

EDIT:

```
~/backend $ ls -laQ
total 28
drwx------ 2 u5587 dyno  4096 Feb 20 16:16 "."
drwx------ 5 u5587 dyno  4096 Feb 20 17:08 ".."
-rw------- 1 u5587 dyno   520 Feb 20 16:16 "server.py"
-rwx------ 1 u5587 dyno 16176 Feb 20 16:16 "test-print"
~/backend $ ls -laq
total 28
drwx------ 2 u5587 dyno  4096 Feb 20 16:16 .
drwx------ 5 u5587 dyno  4096 Feb 20 17:08 ..
-rw------- 1 u5587 dyno   520 Feb 20 16:16 server.py
-rwx------ 1 u5587 dyno 16176 Feb 20 16:16 test-print

~/backend $ id
uid=13747(u13747) gid=13747(dyno) groups=13747(dyno)
```

Comment: Wild guess, but try `ls -l test*` - is there a leading or trailing space in the file name (it would show in quotes)?

Comment: `~/backend $ ls -l test*` gives  `-rwx------ 1 u11198 dyno 16176 Feb 20 16:16 test-print`

Comment: Try `chmod +x ./test-print`

Comment: Okay, my guess was wrong ... it would have shown as `'test-print '`.

Comment: @EmanuelP - that would show as permissions error, not file not found.

Comment: @EmanuelP I think it already has execute permissions

Comment: @ColeWhite Don't think. Ensure. :)

Comment: You could try `strace ./test-print` and then when that doesn't work, `strace strace ./test-print`.

Comment: `strace` isn't available on a dyno unfortunately

Comment: @ColeWhite Please [edit] your question and show the output of `type test-print`. All requested information or clarification should be added to the question. On what system did you build `./test-print`?

Comment: @Bodo I added the output to the question. I built the program on my machine.

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -laQ` and `ls -laq`in `~/backend`. What exactly is "my machine"? The system where you try to run the program?

Comment: @Bodo I mean my local machine, not the one I am running the program on. I added the output you asked for to the question.

Comment: And the output of `id`, please.

Comment: @Bobo I added the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different user names `u5587`  vs `u13747` in the output of `ls` and `id`.

```
~/backend $ ls -laq
total 28
drwx------ 2 u5587 dyno  4096 Feb 20 16:16 .
drwx------ 5 u5587 dyno  4096 Feb 20 17:08 ..
-rw------- 1 u5587 dyno   520 Feb 20 16:16 server.py
-rwx------ 1 u5587 dyno 16176 Feb 20 16:16 test-print

~/backend $ id
uid=13747(u13747) gid=13747(dyno) groups=13747(dyno)
```

User `u13747` does not have the permission to list the contents of the current directory or to access anything in this directory because it is owned by a different user and has no permissions for the group `dyno` or others.

(This does not explain why `cat test-print` would work.)